# Flask url_for Built Error

Tags: flask

I have this line in my code:

```
    print "Location: ", url_for('get_user', id=9, _external=True)
```

The function to that shoudl be this one:

```
@app.route('/api/users/<int:id>')
def get_user(id):
    print "Hello: ", id
    user = User.query.get(id)
    if not user:
        abort(400)
    return jsonify({'username': user.firstname})
```

(The Hello was just for me to see if that function gets triggered - which it doesn`t)

Then the error is this:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1616, in build


raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)

BuildError: ('get_user', {}, None)
```

Do you have any idea why is that?

Thanks for your help!!!

PS.: If it helps I was initially using the [tutorial about building an API with Flask](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask) by Miguel Grinberg which worked in the first place but then I played around and that was it...

Comment: Did you import `get_user` in module, where you call `print`?

Comment: It is all the same file.

Comment: What version of flask and werkzeug do you use?

Comment: Can you give us the *full* traceback of the exception? The error shows that you are **not** passing in `id=9` (the second argument, `values`, is empty).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, also error shows, that url_for can't resolve method.
@Kev, maybe you call `url_for` in two different way?

Comment: @Jimilian: no, it cannot find a method *that doesn't take parameters*. That's something different. If the same function was registered with `@app.route('/api/users/', defaults={'id': -1})` for example, you can use `url_for()` without specifying an `id` value.

Answer (score 0):

`url_for('get_user', _external=True, id=9)` works for me. But `get_user` must be visible for `url_for`.

Comment: It is all the same file.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to change `<int:id>` to `<id>`.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked it today it worked and I do not know what was the problem yesterday...sorry - but many thanks for your suggestions.